# C# WPF - DataGrid - Newest Item on Top

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

A simple question, but with important constraints:  Performance matters.

Consider an ObservableCollection with many thousands of items that is being frequently added to that is bound to a DataGrid.  I would like to be able to populate the newest item on the top of the DataGrid as opposed to pushing it to the bottom.

There are O(n) ways to do this with .Reverse or .Insert(0, obj), but these operations are performance nightmares.

Is there a way I can render the latest item at the top of the DataGrid as a feature of DataGrid, as opposed to manipulating the collection?

Comment: If the purpose is to show the newly added data directly to the user, you can scroll down the datagrid as an alternative way. I faced a similar problem and this was the most efficient solution I could find. I'm looking forward to future answers.

Comment: Maybe add a date property and sort after it ? In WPF I think this would a good idea

Comment: "as a feature of DataGrid"? No. But perhaps you could use a property that returns the latest record and display it above the `DataGrid` or just below the header.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it so:

**xaml**

```
DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding ID}" SortDirection="Ascending" Width="120"
```

**C#**:

```
UserListView.Items.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("ID", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
```